# Refactor a Looping SQL Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

This insert statement works. But, I'm hoping maybe someone can teach me a more efficient way to do this query.  Here's what I've got...

I have a table called Source in which DealerID is a non-unique ID (in this table anyway).  For each DealerID, there are multiple Names.  Example:

```
15  BillBoard
15  Event
15  Newspaper

16  BillBoard
16  Event
16  Newspaper
```

I know, I know. This is a very inefficient way to store this data. We're dealing with a legacy app, and I can't overhaul this data structure right now. SO, what I need to do is add two new records per DealerID.  One for 'Phone', and one for 'Internet'.  So after the insert, it would look like this:

```
15  BillBoard
15  Event
15  Newspaper
15  Phone
15  Internet

16  BillBoard
16  Event
16  Newspaper
16  Phone
16  Internet
```

The sql statement below works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way...

```
declare @SourceTemp table (
   [Id] int identity (1, 1) not null,
   [DealerId] int
)

insert into @SourceTemp select distinct DealerId from Source where DealerId is not null

declare @dealerid int
declare @rowcount int = 1
declare @idcount int
select @idcount = max(Id) from  @SourceTemp

while @rowcount < (@idcount + 1)
begin
    select @dealerid = DealerId from @SourceTemp where Id = @rowcount

    ---------------- Insert Phone
    if not exists (select * from Source where DealerId = @dealerid and Name = 'Phone')
    begin
        insert into 
        Source 
            ([DealerID],[Name],[Service],[CampaignCode],[Description],[Created],[UserCreated],[Active])
        values
            (@dealerid, 'Phone', 'Generic', 'CampaignCode', NULL, GETDATE(), 0, 1)
    end

    --------------- Insert Internet
    if not exists (select * from Source where DealerId = @dealerid and Name = 'Internet')
    begin
        insert into 
        Source 
            ([DealerID],[Name],[Service],[CampaignCode],[Description],[Created],[UserCreated],[Active])
        values
            (@dealerid, 'Internet', 'Generic', 'CampaignCode', NULL, GETDATE(), 0, 1)
    end

    set @rowcount = @rowcount + 1
end
```

**EDIT AFTER:**

I had to make one small mod to the answer by Tom, adding the DISTINCT.  This works...

```
INSERT INTO Source ([DealerID], [Name], [Service], [CampaignCode], [Description], [Created], [UserCreated], [Active])
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.DealerId, SQ.Name, 'Generic', 'CampaignCode', NULL, GETDATE(), 0, 1
FROM
    Source S
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Internet' AS Name UNION ALL SELECT 'Phone' AS Name) SQ
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Source WHERE DealerID = S.DealerID AND Name = SQ.Name)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Source (DealerID, Name, Service, CampaignCode, Description, ...)
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.DealerID, SQ.Name, ...
FROM
    Source S
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Internet' AS Name UNION ALL SELECT 'Phone' AS Name) SQ
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Source WHERE DealerID = S.DealerID AND Name = SQ.Name)
```

Corrected it to include the DISTINCT, since there will be multiple other `Name`s for each `DealerID` out there. If performance is a problem then you can move the `DISTINCT` down to a subquery over the `Source` table and then `CROSS JOIN` from there:

```
INSERT INTO Source (DealerID, Name, Service, CampaignCode, Description, ...)
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.DealerID, SQ.Name, ...
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT DealerID
     FROM Source
    ) S
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'Internet' AS Name UNION ALL SELECT 'Phone' AS Name) SQ
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Source WHERE DealerID = S.DealerID AND Name = SQ.Name)
```

Comment: As a note to the OP this would replace the ENTIRE process you have. No need for tables variables or looping. The whole thing is this insert statement.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you Tom.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: I assume S.Dealer, should be S.DealerId